# Parse JSON Date Epoch Time

Tags: jquery, json, date

I am pulling epoch time from a website via JSON. The information is returned in Unix time and I have a Jquery script that translates it into readable, local time. The data string that my script returns is too long though. I'm looking for a more modern, streamlined date.

**My script returns a date format like this:**

Thu Jul 14 2016 01:28:43 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

**I would like a modern date format that shows what day and what time. Like this:**

- Five hours ago
- 2 days ago
- 33 days ago

**Here is my script**

```
      // Convert post creation time to local time
            var utcSeconds = post.data.created
            var d = new Date(0);
            d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
      // Append local time/date to DIV
            $('#news' + i + ' .redditDate').append(d);
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I know I will have to run a script that pulls the current local time, then some math to calculate the difference between the time the original post was made versus the current time. Here is an example I pulled from stack overflow to get the current time:

```
var displayDate = (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' 
+ (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
```

I'm just not certain how to subtract the date I am currently getting vs the current date. Can that be done while both dates are still in epoch format?

Thanks

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: This is great, I may try both of the suggestions given. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This ended up being my answer actually. Moment.js was incredibly easy to use, even having no experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out PrettyDate plugin of jQuery,by John Resig himself:

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Comment: Well shoot...that seems amazing. So I just point the script to the element housing my epoch time or my already formatted date? I think this is what I'm looking for though!